# Argument 'usersCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's wrong? I have created in this way blocks (controller, html) and they work, but for some reason can not now create a controller and have started work units

index.html

```
script src="bundles/app/scripts/controllers/loginCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

app.js

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/user', {
            templateUrl: 'bundles/app/views/user.html',
            controller: 'usersCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('prApp')
    .controller('usersCtrl',['$scope' , function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Page test';
    }
]);
```

user.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div>
            <p> {{message}} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'usersCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ng/areq?p0=usersCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at assertArg (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1796:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1806:3)
    at http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:9103:9
    at link (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js:977:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8780:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8280:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:7671:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:7546:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://symfonyapi.dev/web/bundles/app/lib/angular/angular.js:7690:16)
```

Comment: did you put `'use strict'; angular.module('prApp')` in `app.js` as well?

Comment: That screen index.html
http://clip2net.com/s/3pSLeAu
Yes, I always write in the early 'use strict';

Comment: not `'use strict;'`, I asked if `app.js` contains `'use strict'; angular.module('prApp')` or not

Comment: Yes, that screen. 
http://clip2net.com/s/3pSPGPn

Comment: Check order import files. This error can be ocurring when put config of $routeProvider before importing controller definitions

Comment: @Emir Marques Can you show any example?

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Something like that 
http://jsfiddle.net/qsborzfw